# ¿Cómo crear un archivo que almacene variables e importarlas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input

¡Hola!

Sigo en mi proceso de aprender Python, y ahora tengo una nueva duda. Si deseara, por ejemplo, asignar a una variable un valor determinado por **input** y luego deseara guardar esa variable en un archivo para importarla... ¿Qué podría hacer?

EJEMPLO:

```
#El usuario asigna una variable con valor determinado
variable_x = input("Introduce un valor:")

#Se crea el archivo y se le almacena la variable
archivo = open("ARCHIVITO.py", 'w')
archivo.write()
variable_x 
archivo.close

#Se importa la variable
from 'ARCHIVITO.py' import *
```

El problema es que justamente porque la variable es introducida por medio de **input**, no puedo darle un valor predeterminado y no sé como hacer que acepte lo introducido por **input**.

¡Saludos y gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer, otra cosa es que sea lo más apropiado. Tienes que tener en cuenta varias cosas:

- Lo que tratas de hacer es generar un módulo Python de forma dinámica, por tanto debes escribir código Python válido en el archivo.
- Cuando se importa un módulo, la extensión no se agrega al nombre de dicho módulo.

---

```
variable_x = input("Introduce un valor:")

with open("variables.py", 'w') as archivo:
    archivo.write(f"variable_y = {repr(variable_x)}\n")
```

---

```
from variables import *

print(variable_x)
```

Dicho esto, considera usar `pickle`, `shelve`, `JSON`, un archivo con estructura personalizada si quieres, etc para ésto.

Comment: Pero, ¿qué pasa si la variable que utilizo se nombra diferente a su original? EJEMPLO: var1 = date(2020, 05, 09) #Esto es en mi código normal; Al copiarla se lee como var1 = datetime.date(2020, 05, 09)